# How to create format files using bcp from flat files

Tags: sql, csv, import, bcp, flat-file

I want to use a format file to help import a comma delimited file using bulk insert. I want to know how you generate format files from a flat file source. The microsoft guidance on this subjects makes it seem as though you can only generate a format file from a SQL table. But I want it to look at text file and tell me what the delimiters are in that file.

Surely this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The format file can, and usually does include more than just delimiters. It also frequently includes column data types, which is why it can only be automatically generated from the Table or view the data is being retrieved from.

If you need to find the delimiters in a flat file, I'm sure there are a number of ways to create a script that could accomplish that, as well as creating a format file.